# jquery -- change HTML table scollbar offset

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, offset, keyup

Is there a way to set the scrollbar offset of a HTML table with jQuery ?

After a keyup event that automatically populates my table (by appending rows), I would like to set the scrollbar offset to the top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after the event use

```
    $('#element').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: It's not working, 

$('#product-table').scrollTop(0);

<table id="product-table" class="listing-table"></table>

My table rows are appended via a javascript function (after the keyup event)


$("<tr class='entry_fill' style='background-color:white;'></tr>").append("<td class='ser'></td><td class='des'></td><td class='sam'></td><td class='pri'></td>").appendTo('#product-table');

Comment: could you send me a link to a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

I am using http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/

$('.tablescroll_wrapper').scrollTop(0);

did the trick. thanks ;)